# How to change the variable of Parent Class from a Child Class (in Python)?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, init

**Practising Inheritence in python**

I am practising inheritance on python. I am unsure how to change the variable name of the parent class.

```
# Parent Class
class Family_Member():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def catch_phrase(self):
        print("I am a family member")
# Child Class
class Mum(Family_Member):
    def __init__(self):
        Family_Member.__init__(self)
# Attempting to change variable of parent class from child class
My_Mum = Mum("Kerry")
```

This gives me

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**Questions**

1. Why does this occur? How do I name my member Kerry without this error
2. Why does this error not occur when I don't include the **init** function in the child class. e.g this code works

   ```
   # Attempt 2
   class Family_Member():
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
        def catch_phrase(self):
            print("I am a family member")
    class Mum(Family_Member): # THIS CLASS IS NOW EMPTY
       pass
     My_Mum = Mum("Kerry")
        print(My_Mum.name)
   ```

Comment: ``Mum. __init__`` doesn't "know" that ``Family_Member.__init__`` receives a ``name``. It especially doesn't "know" that it has to *receive and pass on* a ``name``.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Family_Member():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def catch_phrase(self):
        print("I am a family member")
        
class Mum(Family_Member):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Family_Member.__init__(self, name)
        
My_Mum = Mum("Kerry")
```

should work, does it?